# Function return nothing with multiple files?

Tags: c++

When I run one file, it works perfectly. Then I separate 3 file: header, main, function from that file. It aslo works but return nothing. Here the code:

File Header: printStudent.h

```
//Header.h
#ifndef PRINTSTUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#define PRINTSTUDENT_H_INCLUDED
     void read ();
#endif
```

File Function: readFileCSV.cpp . It read and print from my .csv file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h> 
#include <algorithm>

#define student 1000

using namespace std;

void read (){

ifstream readFileCSV;
readFileCSV.open("studentEn.csv");

if(!readFileCSV.is_open()) {cout << "ERROR: File can't be opened or it doesn't exist" << endl;};

string aMSSV[student];
string aname[student];
string abirthDay[student];
string aaddress[student];

string MSSV;
string name;
string birthDay;
string address;

int countStudent = 0;

while(readFileCSV.good()) {

    getline(readFileCSV, MSSV, ',');
    getline(readFileCSV, name, ',');
    getline(readFileCSV, birthDay, ',');
    getline(readFileCSV, address, '\n');

    int lengthAddress = address.length();

    char charAddress[lengthAddress];
    strcpy(charAddress, address.c_str());

    char newCharAddress[lengthAddress-2];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lengthAddress-2 ; i++){
        newCharAddress[i] = charAddress[i+1];};

    string address(newCharAddress, lengthAddress - 2);
    aMSSV[countStudent] = MSSV;
    aname[countStudent] = name;
    abirthDay[countStudent] = birthDay;
    aaddress[countStudent] = address;

    countStudent ++;
};

    countStudent = countStudent - 1;

    cout << "..................................................STUDENT..........................................................." << endl;

    cout << setw(5)  << left << "STT";
    cout << setw(25) << left << "MSSV";
    cout << setw(25) << left << "Name";
    cout << setw(25) << left << "Date of Birth";
    cout <<             left << "Address";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "...................................................................................................................." << endl;

for(int i = 0 ; i < countStudent ; i++){

    cout << setw(5)  << left << i + 1;
    cout << setw(25) << left << aMSSV[i];
    cout << setw(25) << left << aname[i];
    cout << setw(25) << left << abirthDay[i];
    cout <<             left << aaddress[i];
    cout << endl;
}

readFileCSV.close();

}
```

File main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "printStudent.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

   void read ();

return 0;
}
```

Help me why it's return nothing and give me a solution how can i make it works? Thanks!

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `void foo() { std::cout << "hi\n"; } int main() { void foo(); }`

Comment: Try searching: vexing parse

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
    void read ();
    return 0;
}
```

It is a function declaration in `main` a.k.a. forward declaration. Any expression that starts with a type or void is a declaration. It is a local declaration, thus it doesn't conflict with the globally declared function `read`.

To call the function do it so

```
int main(){
    read ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've written the same in one line.

Comment: It seems you link your program improperly.